# Large 'R' symbol html code?

Tags: html, special-characters

Does anybody know the name and/or HTML character code for this large R? It's used in discrete mathematics when discussing [relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation).

[image]

Comment: Can we see the whole context of the picture or at least get the proper name of the "R"?

Comment: You're asking for an HTML character. I don't think there is one.  would say you use R or an image. The reason is due to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols which appears to show the math symbols and where they can, they've used the relevant HTML character. The work around is to style it with a specific font which matches what you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As that R doesn't seem to appear in that Wikipedia article (or you're using a different font) it's hard to tell. But as you might already notice a lot of the symbols in that Wiki article are actually graphics.

If a [list like this](http://www.barzilai.org/math_sym.htm#greekup) doesn't contain it there is a chance there is no HTML representation as an HTML entity. Consider right clicking it to see whenever it's a graphic.

It might also be available as a [Unicode character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode) in which case you could use `&#x1D4E1;`in order to display it.

If it is not Ctrl+C it or right click and view source to get the possible representation. If you select it prior to displaying the source at least Firefox offers the option of just displaying this specific bit.

Comment: Thanks! `&#x1D4E1;` was what I was looking for. 
Edit: I read the char from a PDF-file, which makes it hard to copy even 'normal' special characters.

Comment: Don't forget that the display of that character can be dependent on the font of the end system displaying it. Depending on the circumstances a graphic could've advantages.